How can I select a daterange and check if it between this year?
EDIT
€:
I have a query that contains all rows where between two ranges but how can I say get all records where start year is contains the year 2024 ?
this is ok
[2024-01-01, 2024-02-10) <- OK
[2024-12-29, 2025-01-10) <- OK
[2025-01-15, 2025-02-02) <- NOT OK BECAUSE NOT INLUCDE year 2024

here is my current code:
select time_range
from holidays
where time_range::daterange <@ daterange('2024-01-01', '2024-12-31', '[)')



This '[2024-12-29, 2024-01-11]' is incorrect and will fail with ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound. 2) Assuming you actually meant '[2024-12-29, 2025-01-11]'::daterange then select '[2024-12-29, 2025-01-11]'::daterange @> '2024-12-31'::date; t.


To get all records where start year is equal to the year 2024, you could extract the lower bound of your ranges and make a simple comparison, like
select
time_range 
from holidays
where extract(year from lower(time_range))= 2024;

Remember that the @> operator means that the specified range or value is fully contained within the daterange value.
To count days contained in a daterange you should write a query like this, using upper and lower functions
select upper('[2024-01-11, 2024-12-29]'::daterange) - 
lower('[2024-01-11, 2024-12-29]'::daterange) as day_count;

select upper(time_range) - lower(time_range) as day_count
from holidays; 

using your data, result is



day_count




40


12


18



And as the title of your question says that

select a daterange and check if it is between this year

to know that you should use a query like this
select case when time_range <@ 
--first day of current year
concat('[', date_trunc('year', now())::date, ', ', 
--last day or current year
(date_trunc('year', now()) + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day')::date, ']')::daterange 
then 'Daterange between this year'
else 'Daterange NOT between this year.' end daterange
from holidays;




daterange




Daterange between this year


Daterange NOT between this year.


Daterange NOT between this year.



Fiddle to test

Hi thank you very much but why it not works when I FILTER BY all time range ?

select time_range
from holidays
where time_range::daterange @> '2024-12-31'::date; (this not working I got no rows)

@locklock123 that column is not mentioned in your question, but I could check, add a complete definition DDL of your table, dummy data and expected result.

I edited my code and there is an example

@locklock123 answer edited also according to your changes.

thank you very much for your help and time!
